# E: Unable to locate package handbrake-cli

Tags: handbrake

I am trying to install handbrake on my raspberry pi 3 running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1041-raspi2 aarch64).
I keep trying all kinds of ways to install handbrake onto my pi, but everything is to no avail. The internet seems to have a consensus on doing it the following way below, but I keep getting the error E: Unable to locate package handbrake-cli. what does this mean?

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake-cli

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package handbrake-cli
```

Comment: I see it available for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in amd64 & i386 only (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/handbrake-cli) not aarch64.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu platforms, there is an official HandBrake PPA, and thus you can install HandBrake directly from the PPA as follows.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk handbrake-cli
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this was the command I was running for hours in various different ways. I am thinking it is just not supported on the pi.